# What is the point of including array's size in a function declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays

I understand how arrays can be passed to functions in c++, but I don't understand what is the point of including array's size in a function declaration when this size is ignored anyway, because what we are really passing to function is a pointer to the first element of the array.

For example if we have following code:

```
void ArrayTest1(int(&ints)[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cout << ints[i];
}

void ArrayTest2(int ints[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cout << ints[i];
}

void ArrayTest3(int ints[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) std::cout << ints[i];
}

int main()
{
    int ints[] = { 1, 2 };
    //ArrayTest1(ints); //won't compile
    ArrayTest2(ints);    //ok
    ArrayTest3(ints);    //ok
    return 0;
}
```

Then from what I understand functions `ArrayTest2` and `ArrayTest3` are identical.

Is syntax used in `ArrayTest2` only meant to make it clear that this function expects an array with 3 elements and passing array with a different size can cause errors? I'm not new to programming, but I'm new to c++ so I'd like to know what is the point of such syntax and when do people use it.

Comment: Try `sizeof(ints)` and see the difference :)

Comment: As an argument, `int ints[3]` is *exactly* equal to `int ints[]`. *And* exactly equal to `int* ints`.

Comment: *Is syntax used in ArrayTest2 only meant to make it clear that this function expects an array with 3 elements and passing array with a different size can cause errors?* -- Yes, or the coder is new to C++ and actually believe they're passing arrays.

Comment: There is no point to the array size in `ArrayTest2`. It is completely ignored. Why did the designers of C decide to alow it? That's a good question and I don't know the answer. Maybe they wanted to confuse newbies.

Comment: And, obligatory: avoid using legacy C arrays. They are trouble, and source of a lot of Undefined Behavior bugs. Use `std::vector` for most situations, `std::array` for some others. Also, learn to pass containers by (const if possible) reference to avoid copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of C++’s major design goals was far reaching compatibility with C. Not supporting all aspects of C-array usage would have been seriously detrimental to this goal.

Your examples even give a good indication that compatibility is indeed the intent, and that C++ would work differently if that hadn’t been the case. Consider your `ArrayTest1()`. It takes a C-array *by reference*, something that does not exist in C. And in this case the array dimension *is* significant.

```
// C-array of length 3 taken by reference
void foo(int (&x)[3]);  

void bar() {
    int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    foo(a);  // Does not compile. Wrong array size.
}
```

Only `ArrayTest2()` and `ArrayTest3()` are exactly equivalent to:

```
void foo(int*);
```

Btw: Bjarne Stroustrup’s [The Design and Evolution of C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html) is a good read if you’re interested in why C++ is designed the way it is.

Comment: There are two points to this answer: (a) C++ accepts references too, even though that's not what we're talking about here; (b) C did it. Not very informative :(

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly know why C permits this (yes, this comes from C), but it is indeed pointless.

Worse than that, the "wrong" dimension would be very misleading to readers of your code.

We might argue that it was to keep the language grammar simple, as the grammar of a declarator already makes the dimension optional (consider `int x[] = {1,2,3}` vs `int x[3] = {1,2,3}`).

Maybe some people use it to document intent; I certainly never would.

Comment: The "language grammar" point is at best superfluous and at worst wrong. Both `[]` and `[n]` are declarators, and the language grammar would already group them together for things like normal variable declarations. I would say it is actually "simpler" to reuse that grouping for parameter declarations than to try to explicitly say "no bounds allowed" (note: modern C actually doubles down on "complexity" and adds things like `[*]` and `[static n]` to parameter declarations). Pointing out that it's useless and shouldn't be used is fine, and I agree, but the *implementation* concerns don't matter.

Comment: @HTNW Hmm yeah that's fair.